# ZK is throwing error while running hbase

Tags: hbase

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerConfig
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 1 more

Answer (score 2):

There's the same situation while running hbase in cygwin with me.
I solved this by editing hbase-env.sh, adding the line:

```
export HBASE_CLASSPATH="C:\hadoop-0.20.2\conf"
```